# Shorthand if statement PHP

Tags: php, shorthand-if

This is a really basic question and I appoligize for asking, but it would be really usefull for me to understand, so I can use this method in the future,

How would I turn

```
if($_GET['page']) {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
  $page = 0;
}
```

Into a simple 1 line shorthand result ?

Comment: The solutions provided are using the ternary operator in PHP. See  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for more info

Comment: But please don't do an `include($page);` afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

A **real simple** shorthand for your statement would be just

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

which would be enough for the most cases.

But you really meant `if (isset($_GET['page']))`, not just `if ($_GET['page'])`
so, one of these ternaries can be used.

However, for the variables like `$page` I would use different strategy, called "**define your variables!**"

So, for the essential variables I would define them all first.

```
$page = 0;
```

and then, when processing request, would set it with some value, is present

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (!is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
         throw new HTTP400()
    } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$page=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use isset() as well for better error handling.

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add standard check:

```
$page=isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:0;
```